# Error using a custom collection for a report

Tags: collection, reports

this is a hard question to ask but I am trying to write a reporting module, following:

http://www.summasolutions.net/blogposts/custom-reports-magento.

I got that module to work on my install, but when I try to customize it or other sample reporting modules I always run up against:

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function setPeriod() on a non-object in
>   /Volumes/Apache/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Grid.php
>   on line 137"

One thing I know is that when I comment out my model spec in config.xml, and point the grid to a different collection like order_collection it works ok except for understandable mismatch between grid columns.  Can you tell just from that what is wrong?  I can pastebin files if you need it.

```
<models>
    <reports>
        <class>VMR_Reports_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>reports</resourceModel>
    </reports>
</models>
```

Comment: No need to pastebin the files. Add the relevant section from your config.xml as a start & we'll go from there.

Comment: Moved your comment to the question.

Comment: And that's under <config><global> ... </></> fyi

Comment: And your resource model prefix config?

Answer (score 2):

**You have *two* issues with your configuration, one local to your extension, and one which blows up Magento's core `Mage_Reports` module configuration.**

There are three basic classes for working with / modeling an entity with Magento's ORM:

- (Data) **Model** - *High-level CRUD interface of one "thing"; delegates to resource model*
- **Resource Model** - Low-level performing CRUD of your thing; read & write access to storage
- (Resource) **Collection** - For building & interacting with result set & representing multiple "things"; read-only access to storage

Both the resource model and the collection classes are defined your module's model resource folder. I suspect that currently your configuration is specifying that both models *and* resource models are stored in the same folder:

```
<models>
    <reports><!-- class group for models -->
        <class>VMR_Reports_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>reports</resourceModel>
                  <!-- ^ points to class group for resource models;
                         should be different from the model class group! -->
    </reports>
</models>
```

When we want a (data) model from this module (say, "report"):

```
Mage::getModel('reports/report');
```

It should be different from the resource model:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('reports/report');
```

But this only works if the value of `global/models/reports/resourceModel` xpath is different from the node name under `global/models` in which it is defined (yours currently isn't). This is really tough to describe and understand, but take my word for it. Your resourceModel value should be something ending `_resource` as a convention.

Your larger problem though is that normally, `Mage::getModel('reports/report')` will return an instance of `Mage_Reports_Model_Report`, because the `reports` class group & prefix is defined in ***Mage/Reports/etc/config.xml***:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <reports>
            <class>Mage_Reports_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>reports_resource</resourceModel>
        </reports>
        <reports_resource>
            <class>Mage_Reports_Model_Resource</class>
        </reports_resource>
    </models>
 </global>
```

Your module, however, is *overwriting* the value of the `global/models/reports` xpath! This means that your module must implement every single class under ***Mage/Reports/Models/*** - likely not what you are intending.

Comment: For context, understand that VMR is like the company, reports is the general project, and I want each controller to be 1 report.  And what I am trying to do is make a custom collection that represents the report data for each report.  Any suggestions on how to organize that would be appreciated.  I am currently doing Model/Controllername/Collection.php